# How to do a simple alert in iOS Swift?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

for simplicity (and debugging) i would lake to call up a very simple warning dialog from any places (!) similar to this:

```
func Warning(myText:String){code}
```

My first try using UIAlertController led to this:

```
func Warning(delegate: AnyObject, message: String) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    delegate.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This works, but only calling directly from a class with, for example:

```
Warning(self,"Hello")
```

but it does not, when used somewhere inside another function. The "self" reference is not (directly) avaialable.

To make it more clear, lets assume:

```
    func A(){
      Warning (self,"Warning inside a function")
}
```

If this function A is called, even in a class , the reference to self is unknown!

Has anybody a solution for this, or do i see the problem not correctly?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, what do you mean by `calling directly from a class, but does not when used somewhere inside another function`?

Comment: To make it more clear, i want to have a simple warning routine, which can be called from anywhere, not only from inside a class but maybe also from inside a function. Of course this function will also be called in a class, but then i would have to transfer this delegate reference also through there. I find this very invonvinient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sample I hope this will help!!! https://github.com/orazz/SampleAlert

[image]

Comment: Please edit the code into the question. Stack Overflow answers are expected to be self-sustainable.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have written `func Warning(myText:String){code}` out of your `class`

and that's why you can call with `Warning(self,"Hello")`

and not getting `self` reference

Get your method inside your class!

So something like this,

```
public class Alert: NSObject {    
    class func presentWarning(delegate: UIViewController, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        delegate.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
}
```

Use this in your controllers as,

```
Alert.presentWarning(self,"Hello")
```

Comment: But then i have to write it in every class i want to use it. Isn't this ineffectively?

Comment: you dont need to, you can add that method in separate class as class method and you can access it with class.method() in all controllers

Comment: Ah! What kind of class (subclass) would be needed, UIView?

Comment: Just tried with "UIViewController": but get a error message "Type 'Alert' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Comment: not needed, NSObject will work.. and also you need to make that class public. So, public class YOUR_CLASS: NSObject {}

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! Just tried "NSObject" but this has no member "presentViewController". It seems, it has to be "UIViewController"?

Comment: Now i get two errors: when using in a function "Use of unresolved identifier ‘self‘" and in a class "extra argument in call", very strange??